# How is V838 Moncerotis Expanding at 10x the speed of light? (It isn't - but sure looks like it)

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy

The first picture from the Hubble Telescope was on May 20, 2002. A subsequent set of pictures culminating in October 2004 showed that it had expanded at about 1 LY per month.  Now as we know there is nothing that can move faster than light, so this must be a lightecho.

Can someone give me a layman description on how this actually happens?

Comment: Assuming you've read [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_echo) on light echoes, can you tell us what still confuses you?

Comment: A related effect would be [the speed of dark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTvcpdfGUtQ), which is rather well explained on VSauce.  If you can understand what is explained in the video, a Light Echo isn't all that far from that, so it should make sense.

Comment: @HDE226868 - my confusion is based on the fact that the dust isn't seen before the nova.  Why isn't ALL of the dust lit up with the nova, instead of just a ring or so at a time....

Comment: [Here is a nice explanation](https://www.spacetelescope.org/images/heic0304f/). The curves are the places from which the reflected flash reaches us at the same time.

Comment: @KeithMcClary - thanks...  what do the purple lines represent?  A shock wave?  Gas?  Trying to figure out what causes the light to reflect.

Comment: By "curves" I meant the purple lines.